# Unable to locate the model you have specified: users

Tags: php, codeigniter, module

When I am going to run my file, it shows an error like this,

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: users
```

I have controller, models and view in Modules folder and I think its a HMVC structure.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: $this->load->model('user_model','user'); The structure is like in modules, there are controller, models and view. And version is 2.2.0

Comment: Make sure your model file name and class name match

Comment: Yes I have.... I have application/modules/users/controller,models,views structure.

Comment: try to post your controller code and model class. it will help to look into insight.

Comment: Make sure name of file use all lowercase alphabets.

Comment: I did the same. @jagad89

Comment: Post your controller and model code

Answer (score 0):

Load the model before you use it.

```
$this->load->model('users');
```

Also make sure that your model starts like:

```
class Users extends CI_Model{  }
```

CI version 2.1.4